# jQuery ajax calls with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, api

These are my code blocks.
API Endpoint

```
      app.get('/clients/zvb/:id', function(req, res) {
console.log('ZVB Query loaded as var = file;')
var path = './public/queries/zvb.sql'
var zvb = fs.readFileSync(path, "utf8")
zvb = zvb.splice(25, 0, req.params.id)
request.query(zvb, function(err, recordset) {
  console.log(recordset);
  res.end(JSON.stringify(recordset));
});
```

})

Then my index.html where I try and GET the data from the endpoint.

```
        $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8081/clients/zvb/16601',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log('we got to here..')
    }
});
```

Not much is happening at the moment. When I try and manually run the ajax call in the terminal I get;

```
    Object {readyState: 1}
```

The endpoint is working, if I view it I can see the JSON i'm after.

Tom

Comment: From the docs you should [res.send()](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send) or [res.json()](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.jsonhttp://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.end) if you want to send data, instead of [res.end()](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.jsonhttp://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.end). And on your Ajax call shouldn't you be expecting 'json' instead of 'jsonp'?

Comment: `dataType: 'jsonp',` why? do you know what jsonp is?

Comment: `readFileSync` never use this method on a server than receives http requests. use the async version instead.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jquery 1.5+ these shorthand methods are very easy to use. 
(I can't comment or would have asked). Doc is here http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/

```
$.get( "http://localhost:8081/clients/zvb/16601", function(data) {
  var data = JSON.parse(data);
  })
  .done(function() {

  })
  .fail(function() {

  })
  .always(function() {

  });
```